# mysql query - can't wrap my head around it

Tags: mysql, select

i have this little PHP script that tracks downloads of files and currently i am fetching the results with this query:

```
SELECT file, COUNT(file) AS downloads 
FROM downloads 
WHERE file LIKE 'pfx_%' 
GROUP BY file
ORDER BY downloads DESC
```

For every new download i create a new row where i keep the filename in one column.
This brings back something like

```
Filename01 | 1200
Filename02 | 100 
Filename03 | 256
...
Filename0x | 932
```

The problem i have now is that some files have versions like Filename01_1.0 and Filename01_1.1, Filename01_1.2 etc

Is it possible to fetch these versions and count them as one Filename?

I hope it makes sense :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do like:

```
GROUB BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(file, '.', 1)
```

Comment: `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(file, '_', 1) AS file, COUNT(*) AS downloads FROM downloads GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY downloads DESC`

Answer (score 1):

The [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) is your friend:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(file, '_', 1) as file, COUNT(*) AS downloads 
FROM downloads 
WHERE file LIKE 'pfx_%' 
GROUP BY file
ORDER BY downloads DESC
```